# Why store data on different rows in a database?

Tags: mysql

I notice that some people store related data on different rows in a database, while some poeple put related data on the same row.

For example

```
  id  user_id  field_id  value
  1      1        9     "name 1"
  2      1       10     "address 1"
  3      1       11     "phone 1"
  4      2        9     "name 2"
  5      2       10     "address 2"
  6      2       11     "phone 2"
```

versus

```
 id     user_id    name         address      phone
 1        1        name 1     address 1     phone 1
 2        2        name 2     address 2     phone 2
```

Here you see two ways of storing the data for user 1 and user 2. I dont know why the first method would be used over the second.

I encounter some databases using the first method, if you want to do a simple thing the SQL statements get exceedingly complicated very fast. While the second method is very easy and straight forward.

Im was wondering if anybody knows why people keep using the first method, and if there is an advantage that im unable to see.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean columns? If people are using it the first way it's bad practice, it doesn't even pass 1NF.

Comment: Wordpress is using the first method to store stuff to the database, its making my life a living hell. To do a simple thing i have to spend over a day getting the SQL right

Answer (score 2):

The first table design allows end-users to dynamically add new fields. Some software might allow you to add new fields to certain things. Many CMS's do this and also applications like Jira. Presumably there's a separate `fields` table where these can be defined.

If you don't have an explicit need for this, avoid this pattern at all costs. It's really the type of thing that you should only do if you are left with no other options, and even then it might make more sense to:

- Only do this for custom fields, but keep the default fields flat
- Maybe use a `JSON` type instead and just dump all the custom data in there. It's not like the key->value table indexes really well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you didnt explain why method 2 should be avoided at all costs, even thought the sql queries seem easier shorter and faster when using method 2.

Comment: @PaulPatt They said method 1 (*first table design*) should be avoided at all cost, not method two which is fine.

Comment: Ok I agree, methid 2 seems better. So why does popular CMS like wordpress use method 1 where it makes sql queries so extremely complicated?

Comment: I described why they do this... to allow users to add new fields dynamically. Let me know if that was unclear. Happy to elaborate.

Comment: Neither method is good.  I would refer you to a discussion of normal forms:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.  It consists of determining the atomicity of a data value and then proceeding based on whether there are limits like closed enumeration of values.

Comment: @TGray instead of suggesting to read normal forms theory, perhaps you can point out specifically what's wrong with the second table design?

Comment: Everet, why cant users add new fields dynamically using the seconds method? I believe its possible to add/remove columns from a table.

Comment: @PaulPatt generally software that deals with databases want to be in complete control over the schema. Generally nobody will dynamically call things like ALTER TABLE or CREATE TABLE except during upgrade / installation procedures. Database schemas should be fixed.

Comment: @Evert I think it's beyond the scope of a comment to teach normalization.  The question is extremely open ended.  I agree with your answers, but this is not a small discussion.  I wasn't trying to be rude, but I think it's almost impossible to teach this a few characters at a time.

Comment: @TGray, yea I just find the comment similar to: yes there's a problem with your design, go get a masters degree in CS. The answer is in there somewhere. If there is a true normalization issue, I think it should be easy to point out, otherwise I don't believe you actually grasp it correctly yourself ;)  I have a hunch what you might be referring to (user_id/id looks pretty similar. It's probably the same field?)

Comment: Evert - I get you want the software to be in complete control of the schema, but the software is the one doing the ALTER TABLE to add more columns, so it DOES have control over it. My problem is the extreme complexity of the SQL statements when the data is spread out over multiple rows like in method 1.

Comment: @PaulPatt I think generally software projects see their options as database schemas that are dynamically altered vs. key->value tables, and consider dynamically altering schemas as the worth as the two options. I think I would intuitively agree.

Comment: When I said 'worth', I meant 'worse'. I'd imagine it's quite hard to manage a default base schema + migrations for future updates + whatever a user may have added to it (but probably shouldn't have).